# With MySQL, how do I insert into a table on condition that the value does not exist in same table?

Tags: mysql

```
insert into student (FirstName,AGE,CITYID) values('guna','26','1')

select * from student WHERE FirstName!='guna';
```

This query showing error.I can't make FirstName column as unique. Please give an idea other than this.

Thanks

Comment: mark your code in code block.. please.. and what is the error you are getting exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql insert if row does not exist already in a table with NO UNIQUE FIELDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969121/mysql-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-already-in-a-table-with-no-unique-fields)

Comment: Duplicate (closer) to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038040/mysql-make-a-field-unique

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO student ( ....)
WHERE FirstName NOT IN (SELECT FirstName FROM student)
```

---

After revision and testing:

```
INSERT INTO student 
    (FirstName, age, cityid)
SELECT 
    'guna','26','1'
FROM student -- any table name will do
WHERE 'guna' NOT IN 
(
    SELECT FirstName 
    FROM student
)
LIMIT 1 -- required because all rows will qualify if 
        -- WHERE clause is satisfied
```

Comment: Correct. Maybe also add this answer to the [mysql insert if row does not exist already in a table with NO UNIQUE FIELDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969121/mysql-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-already-in-a-table-with-no-unique-fields)?

Comment: INSERT INTO student (FirstName,AGE,CITYID) values('guna','26','1')
WHERE FirstName NOT IN (SELECT FirstName FROM student) ,this query also showing an error

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` would probably be faster?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a unique index on that table which will do the same for you

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD UNIQUE <name_of_index>[optional] (FirstName);
```

EDIT:

If you cant use a unique index..

One soln i can think of is using compound statements - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

Comment: I think the question said `I can't make FirstName column as unique`?

Comment: Err.... either I didnt read it or it got added later? Anyways.. if thats what is needed, then le dorfier has the answer.